# image hover effect using wordpress

Tags: wordpress, image

I am a newbie to Wordpress.

I have thumbnails on my website and I want to create a image hover effect of a block colour, when a mouse hovers over an image.  I want the image to still show through, but the block of colour to be grey with some opacity with the image title in white on the grey.

Can anyone advise how I can create this affect?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

There are plugins for that in wordpress here is one [wp visual slide box builder](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-visual-slidebox-builder/)

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Could you provide a quick example of how to use it? Thanks!

Comment: sure here is a link to the demo page [Demo](http://wpvisualslideboxbuilder.com). You can build the animation using the plugin's UI and then save it, the plugin will generate a short-code, simple copy/paste that short-code to a page or post. Here is a video with detailed explanations: [Video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cDoLUATTRDc)